# How do I group by user_id in this SQL query?

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

This is the query I am working with. And the output is attached.

```
spark.sql("SELECT tip.user_id, user.name, tip.compliment_count FROM tip LEFT JOIN user on tip.user_id = user.user_id SORT BY compliment_count DESC").show(40)
```

[image]

Comment: what's your desired output?

Answer (score 1):

```py
spark.sql("SELECT tip.user_id, user.name, sum(tip.compliment_count) compliment_count FROM tip LEFT JOIN user on tip.user_id = user.user_id GROUP BY tip.user_id, user.name SORT BY sum(tip.compliment_count) DESC").show(40)
```